# Make and save change into Forge Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I need to view files with the autodesk viewer and make and save the changes. I wonder if it is possible to do it directly through the Forge API I thought to apply, once the waterfall viewer is loaded, all the preloaded changes in an internal database

The changes I would like to make are of the type:

- adding a room,
- addition of mesh
- addition of successively recoverable properties
- addition of other 3D models preloaded in forge

Answer (score 1):

Since all property data and the SVF itself (or any derivatives for that matter) is immutable once extracted so I am afraid you'd need to programmatically append the mesh (try [SceneBuilder](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer) to make things easier) every time the model is loaded ... As for the properties it's possible to use your own data source for persistence though - see a case in point [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/adding-custom-properties-property-panel) and [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs)

To persist any change to the original design file would require translating the model again for Viewer to consume the changes - however this process can be automated using our Design Automation service and Webhooks ... see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-properties-using-design-automation) to get started.

One possible workaround to persist your custom geometry would be to convert your geometry to OBJ and then SVF with the Model Derivative service (for course that'd incur costs ...) and then load it to Viewer and aggregate with the original model...